# What is the sum of money you get when you have done a job for which you were given an advance

Tags: word-meaning

Let's say I took on a job, for example, driving a truck loaded with goods from one city to another. When I agreed to do the job I was given an advance in order to pay for fuel etc. And when I finish the job I will receive the rest of the money that we agreed upon.

My question is, what do you call that "rest" sum of money that I was given upon completing the job?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use "the [balance](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/balance)".

> 6.1 The difference between an amount due and an amount paid.
>   6.2 (in singular) An amount left over.
>   *Half of this sum will come from contracts with the ARU and the Force, and the balance is sponsorship from businesses*

So, for your situation:

> You will receive an advance of 25% and *the balance* will be paid on completion of the job.