# Deducting an advance from an expense: what (verb) happens to the expense?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

In a company, someone receives an advance payment for expenses he has to make, let's say $200 for hotel costs when traveling on a business trip.
During the trip he pays a larger amount ($300) for his hotel.
Now he comes back at work, with the $300 hotel bill, and he submits his expenses, stating that he still wants to receive $100.

If I phrase that in one direction, I would say: *He deducts the advance from his expense*.

But what is the verb to use in the other direction? What does he do with his expense when (at the moment) he deducts/subtracts the advance from it (in the books)? What verb do I fill in when he uses a computer program to calculate his final expenses (the $100):

*The expense is .... with/from/to the advance*.

In my language, Dutch, we would say *verrekenen*, i.e. something like 'recalculate'.

[This question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/130641/what-is-the-sum-of-money-you-get-when-you-have-done-a-job-for-which-you-were-giv) talks about the **nouns** *advance* and *balance*. Can *balance* be used for the verb too?

Comment: The link on "This question" takes me to the 'ask a question" page. Was that deliberate?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Sorry, fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a bit confusing because "deduct the advance from the expense" is appropriate in one circumstance and "deduct the expense from the advance" is appropriate in a different circumstance. Both make sense in the context of determining who owes whom how much. It is hard to imagine any circumstance other than that of repayment in which the sentences even make sense. The amount of the expense is unaffected by the amount advanced. And the amount advanced is unaffected by the amount of the expense.

In short, two different verbs are not needed.

**If the total advanced exceeds the total of expenses incurred, deduct the expenses from the advances to determine the amount repayable to the employer.**

**If the total of expenses incurred exceeds the total advanced, deduct the advances from the expenses to determine the amount repayable to the employee.**

Comment: OK, I'm going for the *deduct*. That seems most appropriate. Thanks.

Comment: And indeed, our software also has the option in the other direction: deducting the excess advance from the salary.

Answer (score 2):

He goes back to work, submits his expenses and says:
**I would like a $100 reimbursement**.

He received $200, and spent $300. The difference is said to be reimbursed.

The company had given him an advance. He now wants to be reimbursed for the $100 over the advance.

Comment: Sorry, I was asking about *verb* usage. I have added a specific sentence to fill in to the question.

Comment: @Jon Doggen to reimburse the difference, the verb is: to reimburse.Of course, he deducts his advance from his total expenses.

Comment: Yes, but it is not the act of paying/being paid (that is the reimbursement) - it is the administrative action of booking the advance - what happens to the expense at that (earlier) moment.

Comment: I  literal definition of reimbursed is: A reimbursement is a repayment for money you've already spent. When you travel for work, you get a reimbursement for your work-related expenses, like hotel bills and plane tickets, but you'll have to pay for that trip to the circus yourself. **@Lambie is spot on with this answer**.

Comment: @Element115 Thanks. I really know all about this since I have to do it all the time. Expenses are added to the amount owed. Advances are deducted from the amount owed. On my  invoices, I show this as: Total [owed]; [next line] minus $100.00 as an advance. For example. Of course, on the bookkeeping  side, the payor recalculates what they owe me.

Answer (score 0):

> He **applies** his expense to his advance and determines he needs $100 reimbursement.

Using the definition of apply that means "bring to bear".

I don't think English has a word for this that is as exact as the Dutch word, outside of mathematical reasoning (-advance +expense = -/+ reimbursement of employee; which would yield -- "He adds his expense to his advance to determine if he needs to reimburse the company or if the company needs to reimburse him.")  The + and - of expense and advance are interchangeable as long as one is + and one -.  Generally speaking the mathematical reasoning won't be understood since the listener won't be adding a -(neg) to either expression and would add both values thereby incorrectly determining the employee is owed $500.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, your person

> was **advanced** $200 from his company
>   he **deducted** the $200 advance and **added** $100 to pay the hotel
>   when he returned he will be **reimbursed** $100 from his company

in accounting terms

> $200 was **credited** to your person by the company,
>   then he was **debited** $300 for the hotel,
>   ($200 **debited** from the advance and $100 **debited** from the person),
>   and will be **credited** $100 by his company to makeup the **shortfall**